# how can I use sikuliwebdriver with thucydides?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, browser-automation, sikuli, thucydides

[sikuliwebdriver](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver) is not among the supported webdrivers, that can be specified in thucydides configuration. Is there a way to specify it via code, and so one, to make it correctly injected to the Thucydides page objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done.

However it would look kinda ugly:

```
@Managed(driver = "SIKULI")
public WebDriver driver;

@Test
    public void sikuliTest() throws MalformedURLException {
        driver.navigate().to("https://maps.google.com");
        ImageElement image;
        image = ((SikuliFirefoxDriver)((WebDriverFacade)driver).getProxiedDriver()).findImageElement(new URL("file:///C:/temp/part_of_map.png"));
        image.doubleClick();
        image.doubleClick();
    }
```

Is that something that would work for you?

I can talk to John Smart about making this feature. Or you can create a feature request [HERE](https://java.net/jira/browse/THUCYDIDES)

Comment: if not inconvenient to you, please ask him :)

Comment: I didn't take much time to integrate it, however he'd want to see it covered in tests. I'll try to work on it in 2 weeks.